# Difference between cimv2 and default:StdRegProv

Tags: vbscript, wmi

What are the differences between these 2?

```
objReg = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & line & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & line & "\root\cimv2")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cimv2` and `default` are different WMI namespaces, which contain different classes. [`StdRegProv`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393664%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a class inside the `default` namespace giving you access to the Windows Registry. The `cimv2` namespace provides classes like [`Win32_Process`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [`Win32_DiskDrive`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394132%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`Win32_OperatingSystem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

A WMI moniker can consist of several components, most of which are optional:

```
winmgmts:{security-settings}!//host/root/namespace:class.property=value
```

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa389292%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for further information about constructing WMI moniker strings.

Comment: Thanks for the info! :)